# Py.test masks missing imports

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, pytest

I have a piece of code with an extensive test-suite, which we run using py.test. I recently encountered an issue where a new module should have imported a different module to run properly. However, because that module was imported elsewhere in the test-suite, py.test did not raise an error. It wasn't until much later that this bug cropped up. I've created a minimal reproducible example.

## Minimal Reproducible Example

**Project structure:**

```
set.py
fail/
  __init__.py
  thing.py
  other.py
tests/
  test_thing.py
  test_other.py
```

Where these files contain the following code:

**`fail/thing.py`:**

```
import fail

def needs_do_it():
    return fail.other.do_it() + 100
```

**`fail/other.py`:**

```
def do_it():
    return 100
```

**`tests/test_thing.py`:**

```
import fail.thing

def test_needs_do_it():
    assert fail.thing.needs_do_it() == 200
```

**`tests/test_other.py`:**

```
import fail.other

def test_do_it():
    assert fail.other.do_it() == 100
```

## Expected Behaviour

If you try to run the `needs_do_it` function, you should get an error,
since only `fail` is imported, not `fail.other`:

```
>>> import fail.thing
>>> fail.thing.needs_do_it()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "fail/thing.py", line 4, in needs_do_it
    return fail.other.do_it() + 100
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'other'
```

I would expect, then, that a test being run under py.test would expose
this error in importing. However, it totally masks this problem.

## Actual Behaviour

Because `test_other.py` imports `test.other`, py.test masks the error.

```
$ py.test

========== test session starts ==========
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.1.2, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/eswanson/Sandbox/pytest-test, inifile:
collected 2 items

tests/test_other.py .
tests/test_thing.py .
========== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ==========
```

## My question

My quesiton is in three parts:

1. What is the root cause of this issue?
2. Is this expected behaviour for py.test or something I should raise an issue about?
3. Is there anything I can do as a user of pytest for me to get better assurances that I'm not screwing up imports in the future

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens when you import `fail.other` in the Python shell as well, because Python modules are singletons:

```
>>> import fail.thing
>>> fail.thing.needs_do_it()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/florian/tmp/fo/fail/thing.py", line 4, in needs_do_it
    return fail.other.do_it() + 100
AttributeError: module 'fail' has no attribute 'other'
>>> import fail.other
>>> fail.thing.needs_do_it()
200
```